# Loggin function scope, and this. TypeError: custLog(...).bind is not a function

Tags: javascript, logging, scope, this

(I have modified the questions four times, the changed parts in custLog are commented out with corresponding change number. The most recent custLog() is on the top, the previous versions - on the bottom of this description.)

I try to print value of `this` in window, inner and outer functions.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">   

    //HELPING function
        function whatTypeFnc(obj) {
            // Angus Croll  https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/
          return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase(); //array, object, function
        };       

   //The last changes, the custLog up to date.
//CustLog is helping function to log if the variables in array names are in the scope of the calling function, and to log their values.
    var custLog = function ( num ) {
            var nameF = this;  
            var names = ['outerVal', 'later', 'innerVal' , 'innerF', 'paramVal', 'tooLate', 'outerF'];
            var ans = num + ' ' + nameF + " : "; //nameF = : ,   
            if (this) { names.forEach( function(item, index, array) {
                    try { 
                        var nameVar = eval(item);
                        if( eval(nameVar) )  { 
                             if (whatTypeFnc(nameVar) !== 'function' ) {
                                ans+= item + ' = ' + nameVar + ',  ';  
                            } else  {  ans+= item + ' = function,  '; }  }  }  
                    catch (e) {  ans+= item + ' = und,  ';   }
            } ); }
            console.log(ans);
            return ans; 
    };  

    // the code where i use custLog() to log information about the application specific scope of inner, outer functions and window.

    var outerVal = 'outerVal';
    var later;
    var that = this; //refers to window

    function outerF() {
        var that = this;
        //custLog('43').bind(this); //gives the same error: TypeError: custLog(...).bind is not a function.
        custLog('43').bind(that);
        var innerVal = 'innerVal';

        function innerF(paramVal) {    
            var that = this;
            console.log('innerF this='+this);
            custLog('47').bind(that);
            assert( outerVal, "Inner can see the outerVal." );
            assert( innerVal, "Inner can see the innerVal." );
            assert( paramVal, "Inner can see the later_second." ); 
            assert( tooLate, "Inner can see the tooLate," );              
        }
        custLog('53').bind(that);
        later = innerF;
    };

custLog('56').bind(that); //gives the error that custLog('56').bind is not a function
assert(!tooLate,"Outer can't see the tooLate");                
var tooLate = 'tooLate';  
custLog('59').bind(that);
outerF();
custLog('61').bind(that);
later('later_second');   
custLog('63').bind(that);

I am getting the TypeError: `custLog(...).bind is not a function`. Custlog is the following:
56 [object Window] : outerVal = outerVal,  innerVal = und,  innerF = und,  paramVal = und,  outerF = function,  
TypeError: custLog(...).bind is not a function
error source line: custLog('56').bind(that);
```

//***********************************************
The previous code of the question. The problem was that `this` did not refer to the function variables. It was answered by comments below, but now other error arose.

```
I try to print value of `this` in window, inner and outer functions. My logs does not coincide with assert log. Why?
On line 47 `this` refers to `window` instead of `innerF`, one lines 43 and 53 - to `window` instead of `outerF`. Why?
Why i do not got logged `innerF` on line 47?


        // Helping function for assertion and type checking are the same . 
    function assert(value, desc) { .. };
    functio whatTypeFnc(obj) { ... };

    var outerVal = 'outerVal';
    var later;
    var that = this; //refers to window

    function outerF() {
        var that = this;
        console.log('innerF this='+this);
        //custLog('43').bind(this); //gives the same error: TypeError: custLog(...).bind is not a function.
        custLog('43').bind(that);
        var innerVal = 'innerVal';

        function innerF(paramVal) {    
            var that = this;
            console.log('innerF this='+this);
            custLog('47').bind(that);
            assert( outerVal, "Inner can see the outerVal." );
            assert( innerVal, "Inner can see the innerVal." );
            assert( paramVal, "Inner can see the later_second." ); 
            assert( tooLate, "Inner can see the tooLate," );              
        }
        custLog('53').bind(that);
        later = innerF;
    };

    custLog(that, '56');
    assert(!tooLate,"Outer can't see the tooLate");                
    var tooLate = 'tooLate';  
    custLog(that, '59');
    outerF();
    custLog(that,  '61');
    later('later_second');   
    custLog(that, '63');

//The previous question custLog
var custLog = function (ArrObj, num ) {
            var nameF = this;
            if (ArrObj) {  nameF = ArrObj.toString(); } //does not work 
            else { nameF=ArrObj; }   
            var names = ['outerVal', 'later', 'innerVal' , 'innerF', 'paramVal', 'tooLate', 'outerF'];
            var ans = num + ' ' + nameF + " : "; //nameF = : ,   
        if (ArrObj) { names.forEach( function(item, index, array) {
                try { var nameVar = eval(item);
                    if( eval(nameVar) )  { 
                         if (whatTypeFnc(nameVar) !== 'function' ) {
                            ans+= item + ' = ' + nameVar + ',  ';  
                        } else  {  ans+= item + ' = function,  '; }  }  }  
                catch (e) {  ans+= item + ' = und,  ';   }
            } ); }
              /* var descr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( ArrObj, item );
                if(descr) { 
                    if(ArrObj.hasOwnProperty(item)) { 
                        if (whatTypeFnc(ArrObj[item]) !== 'function' ) {
                            ans+= item + ' = ' + descr.value + ',  ';  
                        } else  {  ans+= item + ' = function,  '; }  }  }  */ 
            console.log(ans);
            return ans; 
    };  

// Helping function for assertion. 
    //From Secrets of JavaScript Ninja by John Resig, Bear Bibeault
function assert(value, desc) {
  var resultsList = document.getElementById("results");
  if (!resultsList) {
    resultsList = document.createElement('ul');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(resultsList);
    resultsList.setAttribute('id','results');
  }
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.className = value ? "pass" : "fail";
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(desc));
  resultsList.appendChild(li);
}


The assert results are :

    Outer can't see the tooLate
    Inner can see the outerVal.
    Inner can see the innerVal.
    Inner can see the later_second.
    Inner can see the tooLate,

The log results are :

    56 [object Window] : outerVal = outerVal,  later = undefined,  tooLate = undefined,  outerF = function,  
    59 [object Window] : outerVal = outerVal,  later = undefined,  tooLate = tooLate,  outerF = function,  
    43 [object Window] : outerVal = outerVal,  later = undefined,  tooLate = tooLate,  outerF = function,  
    53 [object Window] : outerVal = outerVal,  later = undefined,  tooLate = tooLate,  outerF = function,  
    61 [object Window] : outerVal = outerVal,  later = function,  tooLate = tooLate,  outerF = function,  
    47 [object Window] : outerVal = outerVal,  later = function,  tooLate = tooLate,  outerF = function,  
    63 [object Window] : outerVal = outerVal,  later = function,  tooLate = tooLate,  outerF = function, 

Why `this` refer to  `[object Window]`  instead of `innerF` on line 47, or `outerF` on lines 43 and 53?

Why on line 47, my log does not see `innverVal=innerVAL` and `paramVal=later_Second`?
```

Comment: If you need to set the value of `this` when calling a function, see [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: that's where you are calling it from.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:

`this` actually doesn't refer back to a function at all. It is related to the execution context of a function, (i.e. where a function is called from).

Your function `custLog` is defined globally, therefore when you call `custLog` inside of the various functions in your code, you are actually executing a reference to that global function and technically calling that function defined in the global scope. Therefore, the execution context for 'custLog', as you call it in your code, is the global object. All globally defined functions and variables exist inside of a global object (which in the browser, happens to be the window object) and that is what `this` refers to.

There are ways in which you can change what `this` refers to by using methods such as `call`, `apply` and `bind`, but I would suggest reading at least through the MDN documents on JavaScript's `this` keyword (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: I do not use `this` in `custLog` function. I use it in `innerF` sentence `custLog(this, 'msg')`; thus` ArrObj` in `custLog` should have `this` value from `innerF`? I am wrong?

Comment: i tried `custLog('num').bind(this);`  which gave the `TypeError: custLog(...).bind is not a function`.

Comment: I would suggest reading this article http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html to help you understand how `this` works in JavaScript. It can be hard to grasp the scope of `this` sometimes. Regarding the `.bind()` function I can't see where you are using it, but this article is a good read on it https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

I could not manage to make nice custLog(msg).bind(this) function.
Examples and suggestions how to make this are welcome.

This answer demostrates how to check specific function scope, which was my aim. I could not manage to make nice custLog(msg).bind(this) function, thu used 5 lines aggregate whenever i log scope:

```
tableObj[tind]={}; tableObj[tind]['msg']=msg; logs=msg+"  :  ";  
namesG.forEach( function(item, index, array) { 
    try {  eval(item); myCallback( item, index, array, eval(item) ); 
    } catch (e) {  myCallback( item, index, array,  'er' );   }             
}); console.log(logs); tind+=1;
```

Nevertheless, i did not find any example online about logging the function scope.
      Thus maybe this code can be useful for some beginer trying to understand the scope.

```
 // The idea is that if we have  a code as this :
var Ass_inF; //will be Assigned to inF
function outF() {
....var inV1 = Math.random();
....function inF(paramVal) { }   
........Ass_inF = inF;   
}//outF
outF();
Ass_inF('final1');
outF();
Ass_inF('final2');
```

We can save `inV1` value in `inner` function `Ass_inF` scope, despite the fact that `outher` function `outF` finished execution.
On the other hand i do not see application of this. 
Why to store value in another function scope?
We can successfully store it directly in some global variable. If we store in the global variable, when we can access it in any function.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

//Full script about scope logging

```
function whatTypeFnc(obj) {
    // Angus Croll  https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/
    return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase(); //array, object, function
};     

//console logs that  outV='+eval('outV')=outV, item=outV=outV, itemVal =outV
//but innerHTML is empty
function   myCallback( item, index, array,  itemVal ) {
    //console.log('inside myCallback 0, item='+ item+', itemVal=' + itemVal);
    if (whatTypeFnc(itemVal) !== 'function' ) {  
        if( itemVal === 'undefined') { tableObj[tind][item] = '| und'; }
        else if( itemVal==='' ) { tableObj[tind][item] = '| empty'; }
        else if( itemVal===null ) { tableObj[tind][item] = '| null'; }
        else { tableObj[tind][item] = '| '+itemVal; }
        logs+=  item + ' = ' + itemVal + ';  '; 
    } else  {  tableObj[tind][item] = '| fnc' ; logs+= item + ' = function;  '; }  
    //console.log('inside myCallback  outV='+eval('outV')+' , item='+item+'='+eval(item), ', itemVal ='+itemVal );
    return logs;
}

var logs, msg, table, rowcnt, cellcnt, row, tableObj, tind;
var namesG = ['outV', 'inV1', 'inV2', 'Ass_inF', 'outF', 'inF', 'paramVal', 'tooLate' ];

var outV = 'outV';
var Ass_inF, AssP_inF;
logs = ''; //used for looing scope variables

tableObj={};  tableObj[0]={}; tableObj[0]['msg'] = 'messages  //   variables';
for (let item of namesG ) {  tableObj[0][item]=item; } tind=1;  

    msg='67, initial, before outF, global scope '; 
    tableObj[tind]={}; tableObj[tind]['msg']=msg; logs=msg+"  :  ";  
    namesG.forEach( function(item, index, array) { 
        try {  eval(item); myCallback( item, index, array, eval(item) ); 
        } catch (e) {  myCallback( item, index, array,  'er' );   }             
    }); console.log(logs); tind+=1; 

function outF() {
    var inV1 = Math.random(); 

    /*msg='82, in outF '; tableObj[tind]={}; tableObj[tind]['msg']=msg;logs=msg+"  :  ";  
    namesG.forEach( function(item, index, array) { 
        try { if ( eval(item) ) {  myCallback( item, index, array, eval(item) ); }
        } catch (e) {  myCallback( item, index, array,  'und' );   }             
    }); console.log(logs); tind+=1;*/

    function inF(paramVal) {
        var inV2 = 'inV2';
        msg='89, in inF(paramVal) '; 
        tableObj[tind]={}; tableObj[tind]['msg']=msg; logs=msg+"  :  ";  
        namesG.forEach( function(item, index, array) { 
            try {  eval(item); myCallback( item, index, array, eval(item) ); 
            } catch (e) {  myCallback( item, index, array,  'er' );   }             
        }); console.log(logs); tind+=1; 

    };//inF

    Ass_inF = inF;
    msg='98, in outF, after Ass_inF = inF '; 
    tableObj[tind]={}; tableObj[tind]['msg']=msg; logs=msg+"  :  ";  
    namesG.forEach( function(item, index, array) { 
        try {  eval(item); myCallback( item, index, array, eval(item) ); 
        } catch (e) {  myCallback( item, index, array,  'er' );   }             
    }); console.log(logs); tind+=1; 


    Ass_inF();
    msg='106, in outF, after  Ass_inF() '; 
    tableObj[tind]={}; tableObj[tind]['msg']=msg; logs=msg+"  :  ";  
    namesG.forEach( function(item, index, array) { 
        try {  eval(item); myCallback( item, index, array, eval(item) ); 
        } catch (e) {  myCallback( item, index, array,  'er' );   }             
    }); console.log(logs); tind+=1; 

    Ass_inF('Ass_1');
    msg='113, in outF, after Ass_inF(Ass_1); ';
    tableObj[tind]={}; tableObj[tind]['msg']=msg; logs=msg+"  :  ";  
    namesG.forEach( function(item, index, array) { 
        try {  eval(item); myCallback( item, index, array, eval(item) ); 
        } catch (e) {  myCallback( item, index, array,  'er' );   }             
    }); console.log(logs); tind+=1; 

};

var tooLate = 'tooLate';  
outF();
    msg='124, after outF()  '; tableObj[tind]={}; 
    tableObj[tind]['msg']=msg;logs=msg+"  :  ";    
    tableObj[tind]={}; tableObj[tind]['msg']=msg; logs=msg+"  :  ";  
    namesG.forEach( function(item, index, array) { 
        try {  eval(item); myCallback( item, index, array, eval(item) ); 
        } catch (e) {  myCallback( item, index, array,  'er' );   }             
    }); console.log(logs); tind+=1; 

Ass_inF('final trial 1'); 
    msg='131, final, after Ass_inF(final trial 1) '; 
    tableObj[tind]={}; tableObj[tind]['msg']=msg; logs=msg+"  :  ";  
    namesG.forEach( function(item, index, array) { 
        try {  eval(item); myCallback( item, index, array, eval(item) ); 
        } catch (e) {  myCallback( item, index, array,  'er' );   }             
    }); console.log(logs); tind+=1; 


    outF();
    msg='138, after outF()  '; tableObj[tind]={}; 
    tableObj[tind]={}; tableObj[tind]['msg']=msg; logs=msg+"  :  ";  
    namesG.forEach( function(item, index, array) { 
        try {  eval(item); myCallback( item, index, array, eval(item) ); 
        } catch (e) {  myCallback( item, index, array,  'er' );   }             
    }); console.log(logs); tind+=1; 

    Ass_inF('final trial 2'); 
    msg='145, final, after Ass_inF(final trial 2) '; 
    tableObj[tind]={}; tableObj[tind]['msg']=msg; logs=msg+"  :  ";  
    namesG.forEach( function(item, index, array) { 
        try {  eval(item); myCallback( item, index, array, eval(item) ); 
        } catch (e) {  myCallback( item, index, array,  'er' );   }             
    }); console.log(logs); tind+=1; 

//Display scope information
table = document.createElement("TABLE"); 
// table.style="1px solid black"; does not work for cells and rows 
for (let indy in tableObj ) {
    row = table.insertRow(indy); cntx=0;    
    cell = row.insertCell( cntx); cell.innerHTML = indy+' ** '; cntx++;
    cell = row.insertCell( cntx); cell.innerHTML = tableObj[indy]['msg']; cntx++;
    cell = row.insertCell( cntx); cell.innerHTML = tableObj[indy]['outV']; cntx++;
    cell = row.insertCell( cntx); cell.innerHTML = tableObj[indy]['inV1'];  cntx++;
    cell = row.insertCell( cntx); cell.innerHTML = tableObj[indy]['tooLate'];  cntx++;
    cell = row.insertCell( cntx); cell.innerHTML = tableObj[indy]['inV2'];cntx++;
    cell = row.insertCell( cntx); cell.innerHTML = tableObj[indy]['paramVal'];  cntx++;
    cell = row.insertCell( cntx); cell.innerHTML = tableObj[indy]['Ass_inF']; cntx++;
    cell = row.insertCell( cntx); cell.innerHTML = tableObj[indy]['outF']; cntx++;
    cell = row.insertCell( cntx); cell.innerHTML = tableObj[indy]['inF']; cntx++;
    // ['outV', 'Ass_inF', 'AssP_inF', 'inV1', 'outF', 'inF', 'paramVal', 'tooLate' ];
    // for ( let indx in tableObj[indy] ){  cell = row.insertCell( indx); cell.innerHTML = tableObj[indy][indx];  }   
}   
document.body.appendChild(table);

    </script>
```

The example output is like this.

```
0 **    messages // variables   outV    inV1    tooLate inV2    paramVal    Ass_inF outF    inF
1 **    67, initial, before outF, global scope  | outV  | er    | undefined | er    | er    | undefined | fnc   | er
2 **    98, in outF, after Ass_inF = inF    | outV  | 0.6047199716839021    | tooLate   | er    | er    | fnc   | fnc   | fnc
3 **    89, in inF(paramVal)    | outV  | 0.6047199716839021    | tooLate   | inV2  | undefined | fnc   | fnc   | fnc
4 **    106, in outF, after Ass_inF()   | outV  | 0.6047199716839021    | tooLate   | er    | er    | fnc   | fnc   | fnc
5 **    89, in inF(paramVal)    | outV  | 0.6047199716839021    | tooLate   | inV2  | Ass_1 | fnc   | fnc   | fnc
6 **    113, in outF, after Ass_inF(Ass_1);     | outV  | 0.6047199716839021    | tooLate   | er    | er    | fnc   | fnc   | fnc
7 **    124, after outF()   | outV  | er    | tooLate   | er    | er    | fnc   | fnc   | er
8 **    89, in inF(paramVal)    | outV  | 0.6047199716839021    | tooLate   | inV2  | final trial 1 | fnc   | fnc   | fnc
9 **    131, final, after Ass_inF(final trial 1)    | outV  | er    | tooLate   | er    | er    | fnc   | fnc   | er
10 **   98, in outF, after Ass_inF = inF    | outV  | 0.5665007054858299    | tooLate   | er    | er    | fnc   | fnc   | fnc
11 **   89, in inF(paramVal)    | outV  | 0.5665007054858299    | tooLate   | inV2  | undefined | fnc   | fnc   | fnc
12 **   106, in outF, after Ass_inF()   | outV  | 0.5665007054858299    | tooLate   | er    | er    | fnc   | fnc   | fnc
13 **   89, in inF(paramVal)    | outV  | 0.5665007054858299    | tooLate   | inV2  | Ass_1 | fnc   | fnc   | fnc
14 **   113, in outF, after Ass_inF(Ass_1);     | outV  | 0.5665007054858299    | tooLate   | er    | er    | fnc   | fnc   | fnc
15 **   138, after outF()   | outV  | er    | tooLate   | er    | er    | fnc   | fnc   | er
16 **   89, in inF(paramVal)    | outV  | 0.5665007054858299    | tooLate   | inV2  | final trial 2 | fnc   | fnc   | fnc
17 **   145, final, after Ass_inF(final trial 2)    | outV  | er    | tooLate   | er    | er    | fnc   | fnc   | er
```